# System.JSONException: Invalid numeric value: Leading zeroes not allowed at input location [1,2]

Tags: apex, unit-test, json, code-coverage, code

I am getting the error mentioned in title of this question when I am calling one of my class method from a test class which is there to send the email with an attachment.
Inside that method which is getting called, the second line mentioned below is causing issue:

```
        Type idArrType = Type.forName('List<string>');
        List<string> wrapperList = (List<string>) JSON.deserialize(attachId, idArrType);
```

The attachId is getting received properly by the method as checked by using syste.debug but what is the role of this idArrType here? As this class was created by someone else, I also have no idea and specially with this JSON issue. Any guidance will be helpful.

Comment: Could you please share what exactly is passed in attachId? It seems like a malformed JSON error

Comment: Also, you can replace Type.forName('...') with List<string>.class

Comment: Id of the attachment record is passed to it..as a string.

Comment: ok will give it a try. But I think the class is working fine as it was builde 1 or 2 years ago. Its just that when I am calling it from a test method now, it is throwing error.May be some modification was done to class as well but I am not aware of it.

Comment: Well, if it's a single Id, then you cannot parse it to array, because it's not an array. You need to change the output type

Comment: `attachId` must be valid JSON list - e.g. `["someId"]`